# What are the differences between Ghost and Niobe?

Tags: enter-the-matrix

Shortly after starting a new save file in *Enter the Matrix*, you are given the choice to play as either Ghost or Niobe.

Are there any gameplay or story differences between Ghost and Niobe? Or do they both play identically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are differences. According to [this Q&A on IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/enter-the-matrix/Q_%26_A):

> Each character has his/her own separate adventure. There is overlap on
>   a couple of stages, but for the most part, each rebel gets a chance to
>   shine in a different way.
>
> [...]
>
> Niobe is all about finesse, so on co-op driving levels, she's behind
>   the wheel. Ghost is more of a trigger man, so the driving levels find
>   him gunning. Ghost's levels also tend to be a little shorter.

Beware for spoilers, on that link there is a complete walktrough of the game.